# options are not shown on react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using `react-select` for the select field. When i use normal `map` function, the options are shown but if I use nested `map` function it does not list the options.

Here is what I have done

```
<Field
  name="subjects"
  label="Destination Subjects *"
  component={SelectField}
  isSearchable
  isMulti
  options={get(props, "destinations").map(destination => {
    return preferredDestination.map(pdes => {
      if (destination._id === pdes.name) {
        if (get(destination, "subjects").length > 0) {
          return get(destination, "subjects").map(
            (subject, idx) => {
              console.log("subject", subject); // it gets printed too
              return {
                name: subject.id,
                value: subject.val
              };
            }
          );
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    });
  })}
/>
```

This does not list any options but I want options based on certain conditions only.

```
<Field
  name="subjects"
  label="Destination Subjects *"
  component={SelectField}
  isSearchable
  isMulti
  options={get(props, "destinations").map(destination => {
    return {
      name: destination.name,
      value: destination.value,
    }
  })}
/>
```

By normal `map` function i was meant to say the above code. This one works but this is not what I want. I want those items as option which matches the subject for particular selected destination only not the subjects of all the destinations.

How can I now show the options based on the conditions like above?

I am getting the following in options while debugging

[image]

Here is the screenshot of what I am getting with vijay's solution

[image]

Comment: Did you check by debugging whats getting assigned to options in nested map, I feel like you are assigning Array of array, you can just evaluate that expression in console and see.., if its so, spread the inner map return values

Comment: Thanks for your comment. which expression do i evaluate to see in console?

Comment: @arung86 as per your suggestion, I debugged and found the options are showing in array of array form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure the resulting array is one dimensional and use `label` for name and `value` for value

Here is the code

```
<Field
  name="subjects"
  label="Destination Subjects *"
  component={SelectField}
  isSearchable
  isMulti
  options={get(props, "destinations").map(destination => {
    // Don't use second map here 
    // if you're just trying to find the matching element
    // in the second array

    if (
       preferredDestination.findIndex(
        pdes => destination._id === pdes.name
       ) >= 0
    ) {
      if (get(destination, "subjects").length > 0) {
          return get(destination, "subjects").map(
            (subject) => {
              return {
                label: subject.id, // change it to label
                value: subject.val
              };
            }
          );
      }
    }
    // remove unwanted else block
    return null
    })
    .filter(x => x !== null) // remove null elements
    .reduce((a, c) => [...a, ...c], []) // this will convert the 2D array to 1D 
  }
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I am getting the result in the above way with your solution.

Comment: Is that the expected one you meant to say by saying one-dimension array?

Comment: Updated, check now
I didn't notice the second map there

Comment: I think this will give the options as `[Array(1)]` but I will try and see if this works or not.

Comment: I am getting the following result `options [Array(1)] -> options[[{label: "", value: "" }]]` instead of options as `[{label: "", value: ""}, {label: "", value: ""}]`

Comment: Hey hey, My bad. Added array reduce, It should work now

Comment: Thanks it's working now. I was not aware about reduce function. Thanks for helping me.